# Codeigniter curl class file upload

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, curl

I am trying to upload a file using curl class in codeigniter. 
This is the code i am using:

```
$this->curl->create("http://localhost/jobs/api/job");
$this->curl->post(array(
    'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
    'description' => $this->input->post('description'),
    'category' => $this->input->post('category'),
    'image' => '@' . $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],
    'doc' => '@' . $_FILES['doc']['tmp_name']
));
```

This code is in a method that receives the file from a form and sends it to a REST api.
The problem is that the api does not receive any file. It receives any other POST data but not the files.

These are the errors:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: image
Filename: models/jobs_model.php
Line Number: 44

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: doc
Filename: models/jobs_model.php
Line Number: 55
```

Comment: How you are uploading the files, why not using `CI`'s file upload library and make sure your form is `enctype = multipart/form-data`.

Comment: Check [CI FILE Upload](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html).

Comment: I know how the file upload library works. But i really need to upload the files using RESTful services